# XPCE Prolog command causing error in VS2008 C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, swi-prolog, xpce

Upon loading into a C++ program a Prolog program that contains the command 'send' (xpce graphics), I get error messages of type:

```
Syntax Error: Operator Expected.
```

Here is an example command that causes the errors:

```
send( Dialog, append, button(continue, message(@prolog, clear_my_blackboard)) ),
```

I used to get the same errors when I used the plld.exe utility for interfacing my C++ and Prolog programs.  At the time, I thought the problem was that plld was for some reason incompatible with xpce graphics.

But now that I consult (load) my Prolog source files into my C++ files using:

```
PlCall( "consult(myPrologFile.pl)" );
```

I still get these error messages.  I could comment out the lines that contain xpce-specific commands, but I'd rather know what the problem is and how I can circumnavigate it.  So, I would appreciate any help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ is apparently unknown!

It is loaded by the 'rc' file in the SWI home dir and realizes the XPCE binding. I should load this by hand, using:

```
consult( swi( 'plwin.rc' ) )
```

All my pl and xpce source files were compiled successfully.

I am interfacing C++ and Prolog to connect a cognitive architecture written in Prolog to a robotic simulator written in C++.  I am using SWI version 5.8.0 so I had to use the following line in my C++ program to achieve that:

```
PlCall( "consult( swi( 'plwin.rc' ) )" );
```

This command resulted in:

```
swi(plwin.rc) compiled into link_xpce
```

Thanks to Jan Wielemaker.